# Não consigo validar a senha do usuário e também não consigo cadastrar outro usuário

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
caixaBombom = []
cadastro = []

class Chocolate (object):
    def __init__(self, nome, peso, quantidade):
        self.__nome = nome
        self.__peso = peso
        self.__quantidade = quantidade

    def get_nome(self):
        return self.__nome

    def get_quantidade(self):
        return self.__quantidade

    def get_peso(self):
        return self.__peso

    def comer(self, quantidade):
        if (self.__quantidade - quantidade) > 0:
            self.__quantidade = self.__quantidade - quantidade
        else:
            print(f'A caixa não possui {quantidade} do {chocolate.get_nome()}')
            return False
        return True

class Usuario(object):
    def __init__(self, usuario, senha, status, estomago, quant):
        self.__usuario = usuario
        self.__senha = senha
        self.__status = status
        self.__estomago = estomago
        self.__quant = quant

    def get_usuario(self):
        return self.__usuario

    def get_senha(self):
        return self.__senha

    def get_estomago(self):
        return self.__estomago

    def get_quant(self):
        return self.__quant

    def get_status(self):
        return self.__status

    def irBanheiro(self):
        self.__quant = 0
        self.__estomago = 0
        self.__status = "normal"
        print('Você se aliviou!')

    def comerBombom(self, chocolate):
        quantidade=input('Quantos?')
        if not chocolate.comer(quantidade):
            return

        elif self.__status == "saltisfeito":
            while True:
                opcao=input(f'TEM CERTEZA QUE QUER COMER OUTRO \n[S] SIM\n[N] NAO')
                if opcao == 'S':
                    self.__estomago += chocolate.get_peso()*quantidade
                    self.__quant += quantidade
                    if self.get_estomago() > 200:
                            self.__status = "cheio"
                if opcao == 'N':
                    print(f'É bom mesmo você já comeu {pessoa.get_quant()} bombons')
        elif self.get_status() == 'cheio':
            print("Você já comeu de mais, precisa ir ao banheiro primeiro!")
            menu()
        else:
            self.__estomago += chocolate.get_peso()*quantidade
            if self.get_estomago() > 100:
                self.__quant += quantidade
                self.__status = "saltisfeito"

def cabecalho(text):
    
        print(f"{'='*40:^40}")
        print(f"{text:^40}")
        print(f"{'='*40:^40}")

def colocarChocolate(quantidade):
    if chocolate.get_quantidade() == 20 :
        print(f'Caixa de Bombom cheia')
    elif (quantidade + chocolate.get_quantidade()) > 20 :
        print(f'Esta quantidade irá exceder a capacidade da caixa')
    else:
        print("AQUI EU TO ENCHENDO MURCILHA")

def login():
    cabecalho('LOGIN')
    nome = input("Digite o nome da pessoa:")
    senha = input("Digite a senha:")
    achei = False
    for nome in cadastro:
        achei = True
        if  usuario.get_usuario() == nome and usuario.get_senha() != senha:
            print('Senha invalida!!')
            return login() 
        if usuario.get_usuario() == nome and usuario.get_senha() == senha:
            acessoPessoa(usuario.get_usuario)
    if not achei:
        print('Usuário não encontrado!')
        menu()
    
def acessoPessoa(nome):
    nome = nome
    achei = False
    for nome in cadastro:
        achei = True
        cabecalho(f"Nome: {usuario.get_usuario}")
        print(f"Esta: {usuario.get_status()}")
        print(f"{'-'*40:^40}")
        print(f"{'1- Comer bombom':<}")
        print(f"{'2- Adicionar Bombom':<}")
        print(f"{'3- Visualizar caixa de bombom':<}")
        print(f"{'4- Ir ao banheiro':<}")
        print(f"{'-'*40:^40}")
        opcao=input('Escolha:')
        if opcao == "1":
            comerBombom()
        elif opcao == "2":
            usuario.irBanheiro()
            menu()
        elif opcao == "3":
            adicionarBombom()
        elif opcao == "4":
            verCaixa()
        else:
            print("ELSE CADASTRO PESSOAS")

def menu():
    while True:
        cabecalho('MENU')
        print(f"{'1- Login':<}")
        print(f"{'2- Adicionar Pessoa':<}")
        opcao=input('Escolha:')
        if opcao == "1":
            login()
        if opcao == "2":
            adicionarPessoa()

def adicionarPessoa():
    usuario = input('Digite o nome de Usuário:')
    senha1 = input('Digite uma senha:')
    senha2 = input('Confirme a senha:')
    if senha1 == senha2:
        status=input("Como ele está?\n[1] Normal\n[2] Satisfeito\n[3] cheio\n")
        if status == "1":
            pessoa = (usuario,senha1,'normal',0,0)
            cadastro.append(pessoa)
            login()
        elif status == "2":
            pessoa = (usuario,senha1,'satisfeito',0,0)
            cadastro.append(pessoa)
            login()
        elif status == "3":
            pessoa = (usuario,senha1,'cheio',0,0)
            cadastro.append(pessoa)
            login()
        else:    
            print("Opção inválida. Por favor, tente novamente.")
            adicionarPessoa()
    

def comerBombom():
    if len(caixaBombom) == 0:
        print(f'{"Caixa de bombom está vazia!":^40}')
        menu()
    else:
        for chocolate in caixaBombom:
            print(f"{chocolate.get_quantidade():^5} - {chocolate.get_nome():^10}")
        chocolate=input('Qual bombom você quer comer?\n')      
        achei = False
        for chocolate in caixaBombom:
            achei = True
            usuario.comerBombom(chocolate)
        if not achei:
            print('Escolha outro bombom!')
                    
def adicionarBombom():
    nomeChocholate = input("Digite o nome do bombom:")
    achei = False
    for nomeChocholate in caixaBombom:
        if chocolate.get_nome() == nomeChocholate:
            achei = True
            print(f"Nome: {chocolate.get_nome()}")
            print(f"Tem: {chocolate.get_quantidade()}")
            print(f"Cada um tem: {chocolate.get_peso()}g")
            return menu()
    if not achei:
            peso = input("Qual é o peso unitário:")
            quantidade = input("Quantos vão ter?")
            chocolate = Chocolate(nomeChocholate, peso, quantidade)
            caixaBombom.append(chocolate)
            return menu()

def verCaixa():
    if len(caixaBombom) == 0:
        print('A caixa de bombom está vazia!')
        return menu()
    else:
        cabecalho('CAIXA DE BOMBOM')
        print(f"{'Quant':<5} - {'Nome':^10}")
        for chocolate in caixaBombom:
                print(f"{chocolate.get_quantidade():^5} - {chocolate.get_nome():^10}")
                return menu()
      

menu()
```

Se eu tento fazer o login sem ter ninguem cadastrado, ele faz a verificação correta, faço o cadastro de um novo usuário normal, mas quando vou "logar" neste usuario da o erro a baixo.

> if  usuario.get_usuario() == nome and usuario.get_senha() != senha:
> NameError: name 'usuario' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Usuario'?

Comment: e nesse método "login" de onde vem a variável "usuario"? o erro é claro, não está definido

Answer (score 0):

Você criou a classe Usuario mas não instanciou nenhum objeto dessa classe. Parece que você queria criar um objeto com o nome pessoa, na função definirPessoa:

```
pessoa = Usuario(usuario,senha1,'normal',0,0)
```

A forma que você está usando não dá erro, mas também não cria um objeto, na verdade você está a criar uma tupla chamada pessoa com 4 valores.

Comment: Sua resposta foi bem clara e tirou minha dúvida. Não foi arrogante, hoje tem muitos que não tem paciencia para que está estudando e aprendendo. Obrigado

Comment: agora que você está criando o objeto Usuario e carregando no dicionario cadastro, experimenta modificar o for das funções login e acessoPessoa (substitui "for nome in cadastro" por "for pessoa in cadastro". Isto vai percorrer os objetos que foram sendo adicionados ao cadastro.